# can't find elements in HTML page Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to extract the image URL and the description from the items' webpages in this website (https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/), we can take this product as an example (https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/product/rewe-to-go-obstschale-frucht-mix-150g-11014167/).
I 've been trying to get it with find method and it's just returning `None`

```
p = 'https://www.goflink.com/de-DE/shop/product/rewe-to-go-obstschale-frucht-mix-150g-11014167/'
f = requests.get(p,headers=headers).text
hun = BeautifulSoup(f,'html.parser')
description = soup.find("div", {"class" : "product-info-tab-accordion"})
image_url = hun.find("div", {"class" : "v-hl-container v-hl-snap-center"})
print(description)
print(image_url)
```

**Thanks in Advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Script is working for description, but you have to check your variables, so replace:

```
description = soup.find("div", {"class" : "product-info-tab-accordion"})
```

with:

```
description = hun.find("div", {"class" : "product-info-tab-accordion"})
```

To get the images you have to access the content of the last `script` on the page or use their api https://consumer-api.goflink.com/v3/products.

Comment: Description problem has been solved, but still stuck in the image one